# how to set the seed value for ruby murmur hash

Tags: ruby, jruby, hashcode, murmurhash, minhash

Is there a way to set the seed value for using the ruby hash function (i.e. murmur hash in 1.9, don't know JRuby?)  so that I can get the same hash code every time I run the script (i.e. in parallel on multiple processes or on different nodes)

so that

puts "this is a test".hash

is the same whenever I run this , today, tomorrow, 3 weeks from now, etc

I want to do this so I can implement MinHash in parallel

I can see in the murmur_hash gem that the murmur hash accept a seed so I assume I can set the seed and get the hash code deterministically whenever I choose the same seed

Comment: Can you tell us which gem(s) you have installed and `require`d

Comment: Forcing the hash to be the same value could open your code to exploits. Hashes are forced to be random on purpose.

Answer (score 3):

try this seed 0xbc9f1d34, from jeff dean's LevelDB source code, :)

Answer (score 1):

Reviving this if anyones wants to know...

You can use the `murmurhash3` gem [located here](https://github.com/funny-falcon/murmurhash3-ruby).

You can override the hash function built into `String` class.

```
require 'murmurhash3'
class String

  SEED = 12345678

  def hash
    MurmurHash3::V32.str_hash(self,SEED)
  end
end
```

No you can use this hash function on any string.

```
$ irb
2.1.1 :001 > "this is a test".hash
=> 553036434
```

Assuming you use the same **seed** `12345678`, then you should repeatedly get the same hash on any server, process, thread.

#### MurmurHash in Parallel

You can `parallel` gem [located here](https://github.com/grosser/parallel)

Then simply pass the list of items you want to be executed/hashed in parallel.

```
items_to_hash = ['val0', 'val1',...., 'valN']
results = Parallel.map(items_to_hash) do |item|
   item.hash
end
```

If you not into using another gem to execute the hashes in parallel, then here is an example to use vanilla Ruby to get you going.
http://t-a-w.blogspot.com/2010/05/very-simple-parallelization-with-ruby.html